# Can't import Japanese characters from XML to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, encoding, import

I've been trying to load some dictionary files into a MySQL Database for a while but I can't figure out how to do it.

Example of an XML entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
<keb>召す</keb>
<reb>めす</reb>
<sense>
<gloss>to call</gloss>
<gloss>to invite</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss>to eat</gloss>
<gloss>to drink</gloss>
</sense>
</entry>
```

So  is one word. When I import this using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE the columns which are supposed to store the Japanese characters are just left blank. How can I fix this?

I've tried to set my keb and reb rows in the table to utf8_bin and utf8_unicode_ci but still they are just left blank. I'm using PHPMyAdmin if that is any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same apparent problem and I think this is just a PHPMyAdmin "feature".

If I get the data from the database into an array, it is displayed garbled when `print_r` is used. If I use `echo` to output the particular column, then the browser displays it fine (proper JP characters).

The encoding for the db column is set to `utf8_unicode_ci` and I'm not using utf8_encode or `utf8_decode`.

Good luck!